# What was Sauron saying in Dol Guldur while Galadriel carries Gandalf before she said she's not alone?

Tags: the-hobbit, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

Can anyone help me know the English as well as the speech that Sauron said and used in Dol Guldur while Galadriel carries Gandalf and before she said she's not alone? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

According to [a transcript you can find online](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hobbit:_The_Battle_of_the_Five_Armies), you can see:

```
> Necromancer [subtitled]
Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky.
Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone.

> Galadriel
Nine for mortal men doomed to die.

[the Nazgul then show up and surround Galadriel]

> Necromancer [subtitled]
You cannot fight the shadow.  Even now you fade.
One light alone in the darkness.

> Galdriel
I am not alone.
```

Given the poem that the Necromancer/Sauron and Galadriel say here is the inscription on
the one ring, a poem that is known to be written in the language of Mordor, its likely he
says it in that language and we see the translation in subtitles.

Later the Necromancer says

```
Necromancer: [subtitled]
It has begun. The East will fall. So shall the Kingdom of Angmar rise.
The time of the Elves is over. The Age of the Orc has come.
```

Comment: Whoa! Amazing! What about the speech he used? Is it possible to know the entire words he spoke? The only clear thing I recall he said was "ami kuzdu bagul undumishi bagul"

Comment: I cannot find a source for what he says in the Mordor 'black speech'

Answer (score -2):

Before the Nazgûl shows up, the necromancer says the beginning part of the ring poem (the part not written on the ring).

[Black speech] Necromancer : "Shre nazg golugranu kilmi-nudu. Ombi kuzddurbagu gundum-ishi (bagu)"
[English] Galadriel : "Nine for mortal men doomed to die."